# HTML input file - Allow uploading file from a web site

Tags: html, file, upload

I have a web site, let's say "mywebsite.com.local" with a section "mywebsite.com.local/documents" containing some files (.xls, .doc, .pdf ecc..). From another application I would like to allow an user to choose from one of those files, and tipically if I want to browse in the file system I just put an input tag in html:

```
<input type="file"...>
```

But what about the case of an external file? I want the user to click on "Browse..." button and find himself on the page "mywebsite.com.local/documents" in order to choose a file. In this case choosing a file it has not to be uploaded anywhere, but I just need it's URL.

Answer (score 0):

> I want the user to click on "Browse..." button and find himself on the page "mywebsite.com.local/documents" in order to choose a file.

You can't do that. File inputs (and the browse buttons they generate) are solely for accessing the user's local files.

Instead, put the list of documents in the form. Add a checkbox or radio button next to each one to allow the user to select one or more of them.